# Sprintf turning massive number into '4'

Tags: c, pipe, printf, atoi

I am trying to pass a pipe and need to convert its identifiers into strings. My problem is that currently sprintf is turning the identifiers into '4' as a string, which the process being passed to obviously can't use (note: it is being converted to 4 in the issuing process so the problem is not the pass itself)
Code:
Issuing process: (PipeC.c)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){  
    int fd[2], B, C, D, numberRead, i, pipeReturn, *code;
    char *arg[4];
    char charsRead [10000], fdNumberAsString[256];

    pipeReturn = pipe(fd);
        if(pipeReturn < 0){ printf("error creating pipe\n"); return;}
    sprintf(fdNumberAsString, "%d", fd[0]);
    arg[0] = "PipeW1";
    arg[1] = fdNumberAsString;
            //printf("%d\n", fdNumberAsString);
    sprintf(fdNumberAsString, "%d", fd[1]);
            //printf("%d\n", fdNumberAsString);
    arg[2] = fdNumberAsString;
    arg[3] = NULL;

    printf("PipeC - fd[0] = string: %s    int: %d\n", arg[1], arg[1]);
    printf("PipeC - fd[1] = string: %s    int: %d\n", arg[2], arg[2]);

    //printf("fd[0] = %d, fd[1] = %d\n", fd[0], fd[1]);

    B = fork();
    if(B == 0){
        execv("PipeW1", arg);
        printf("execv failed\n"); 
        exit(1);
    }
    

    close(fd[1]);

    numberRead = read(fd[0], charsRead, 5);
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)printf("%c ", charsRead[numberRead]);
    wait(code);
    exit(0);
}
```

Created Process (PipeW1.c):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int x, char** args){ 
    printf("here\n");
    int fd[2], pipeReturn, *ptr;
    char num[256];
    fd[0] = strtol(*(args+1), &ptr, 10); 
    printf("%d\n", fd[0]);
    printf("PipeW1 - fd[0] = int: %d\n", fd[0], fd[0]);
    fd[1] = atoi(*(args+2));

    printf("PipeW1 - fd[0] = string: %s    int: %d\n", fd[0], fd[0]);
    printf("PipeW1 - fd[1] = string: %s    int: %d\n", fd[1], fd[1]);

    close(fd[0]);
    write(fd[1], "12345", 5);

    exit(0);
}
```

Resulting output:

````
[myname@myserver folder]$ PipeC
PipeC - fd[0] = string: 4    int: 1061374320
PipeC - fd[1] = string: 4    int: 1061374320
4
4
     [myname@myserver folder]$```
````

Comment: What  do you expect the result to be? You are trying to print a string as an int which is undefined behaviour. It's really unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Pointers (like `arg[1]`) are not integers, you can't print a pointer as an `int` value using `%d`. At the opposite end, `int` values (like `fd[0]`) are not strings, and can't be used with `%s`.

Comment: *Sprintf turning massive number into '4'*. No it's not. It's turning the integer `4` into the string `"4"`. It's the "massive number" that is the wrong result and that is because you are trying to print a string as an int.

Comment: you cannot reuse `fdNumberAsString`,  `arg[1]` and `arg[2]` will be the same string with the last value

Comment: Is using spritntf to convert an int to a string really that bizarre? It seems to be recommended all over StackOverflow @kaylum

Comment: It's not bizzare at all and nobody is saying that. `sprintf` is doing exactly the right thing. What we don't understand is why you think `4` is not the expected output. At least that's what it seems you are saying. It's unclear what you are really saying and asking.

Comment: So de-reference arg[whatever number]? I'm a bit confused because I thought that [] was a dereference equivalent here but apparently not @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: gotcha, thanks, and I am trying to pass a file identifier between processes which seemed clear to me but apparently was not @kaylum

Comment: You should take a step back. Your approach is likely wrong. The standard way to set up pipes is to do it all before the `exec` call. That is, the child process should not need to know anything about the pipe. It just reads from stdin and writes to stdout. It is the parent's job to set up the pipe and file descriptors such that the child will actually be reading/writing via the pipe.

Comment: I am not allowed to use dup or dup2... hence this incredibly jank approach.. which I like to think contributed to the confusion in addition to my poor communication here @kaylum

Comment: `arg` is an array (of `char *`). Using `[]` fetches a specific element from that array. That element is a `char *`. This `char *` is a pointer to the first element of a null-terminated string. What that `char *` element is *not* is an `int` value. The `printf` format `%d` expects a value of type `int`, and you pass it a `char *`. Mismatching format specifier and argument leads to *undefined behavior*. Would you expect e.g. `printf("%d", "hello")` to work? You have the same issue here.

Comment: Ah, I see, thank you @Someprogrammerdude